# Shopify - get customer email from customer object? (js - scripttag)

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify, script-tag

I need to create a cookie with clientID(need email to create it), when customer register/login on shopify shop.

How can I get email during register/login? Is it possible to get it from Customer object(js injected via script-tag) and how? The only possible way I see at the moment is to create onclick event on register/login and catch customer e-mail from post?

CustomerId (__st.cid) won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the `{{customer.email}}` attribute.

Once the user register he is redirected to the account page and he is logged in already.

So on the account page you just create the cookie by passing the `customer.email` to a script and set it there.